# Loop items in jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

In my page I have a sortable.
At current I have some code like this to return the sort order ";" separated:

```
JsonChainProcessData.ProcessItemOrder = $(processConstants.chainProcessId).sortable('toArray').join(';');
```

The `toArray` function works with the id's of the items in the sortable.

What I need is to have a similar list but now with the value of my custom attr 'pid' instead of 'id'.

My problem is that I have no idea how to loop the items in the sortable and ask them for their attr 'pid'.

for the record I know I can use `$(processConstants.chainProcessId).each(etc...)` but this of course is not the same as looping the items IN the sortable.

Thanks,
Joost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toArray` method takes an undocumented `options` argument that can override the attribute used in the returned array (see line 404 in the source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js)).

If you don't mind using this undocumented parameter, you can write:

```
JsonChainProcessData.ProcessItemOrder
    = $(processConstants.chainProcessId).sortable("toArray", {
        attribute: "pid"
    }).join(";");
```